# Bash Return 'Command not found' for all command

Tags: terminal

I am learning Linux command from terminal,

It feedbacks 'command not found' for every command even though executed successfully.

```
$ > foo.txt
bash: prompt_git: command not found
$ umask
0022
bash: prompt_git: command not found
```

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is caused by a bad setting in your `.bash_profile` file.

One of the shell variables `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` contains a call to `prompt_git` which is not (at that point) in your PATH. `PS1` defines the prompt you see in the terminal and `PROMPT_COMMAND` is run every time the prompt is displayed.

Edit the file and remove the command and it will resolve your problem.

If you wish further help then please post the definitions of `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` from your `.bash_profile` file.